# How to make a button that changes lamp energy in BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine, light, logic-bricks

I am creating an options menu for a simple game. I want to make a button that will adjust my lamps energy up or down.

I would like both ways,  a button that adjust the lamp energy up and a way to adjust it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
light = scene.lights['Lamp']

if cont.sensors['Mouse1'].hitObject.name == 'button.up' and cont.sensors['Lclick'].getButtonStatus(bge.events.LEFTMOUSE) == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
    light.energy += 0.5

if cont.sensors['Mouse1'].hitObject.name == 'button.down' and cont.sensors['Lclick'].getButtonStatus(bge.events.LEFTMOUSE) == bge.logic.KX_INPUT_JUST_ACTIVATED:
    light.energy -= 0.5
```

Attach this script to your two buttons with these logic bricks. The two buttons must be named `button.down` and `button.up`, or you will have to change the names in the script.
[image: logic bricks]

The two buttons will increase and decrease the default `Lamp` energy by `0.5` per click.

Answer (score 4):

The "I'm not a programmer!" approach.

**First step:**
Create the button(s), create the light.

**Second Step:**
Create an animation for the lamp where it is dim at frame 1 and bright at frame 200.

**Third Step:**
Switch to game logic and add a property to the light named *Bright*. Make an *action* actuator with the play mode set to *property* set the property and the frame property of the actuator to be *Bright*. Do the rest of the setup as follows.

[image: Logic setup]

This basically means *If the mouse is over the button (cube) and the mouse is clicked, add two to the* Bright *property. Play the PointAction as* Bright *is increased.*

**Forth step:** (optional)
Add an always sensor and a mouse visibility if your game has no way of knowing where the mouse is. Create another button with the *exact* same setup except make the property *Bright* decrease by two under the *property* actuator

Comment: I didn't even know that you could have animated lamps playing in the BGE! (jeep's headlights will be toggling on/off very soon.)

Comment: Learned a trick or 2 from BRSky